# CKEditor Codesnippet's background not scrolling past <div> length

Tags: html, css, ckeditor, highlight.js, django-ckeditor

I created a div in my a web site so that the text on the page is neatly contained to a set width. I've also implemented CKEditor5 and am using it's CodeSnippet plugin. When there is too much code on a line, it creates a scrollable box with the text overflowing in that scrollable part (behaviour that I actually desire!). However, the background does not exert that same behaviour so that it looks quite unreadable as you can see in the picture below.

I am quite new to building websites so I don't actually know where to start, Should look into the HTML or do I need to set some configuration in CKEdtior?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/qLCrF.png

Cheers,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found that the issue only arises when I apply a custom style like monokai-sublime.css.

adding

```
overflow-x: auto;
```

to

```
.hljs {
       display: block;
       padding: 0.5em;
       background: #23241f;
}
```

in monokai-sublime.css fixes the issue for me.